# Distribution of number of Bernoulli trials before some large number of sucess

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, bernoulli-process

We repeatedly make an experiment where we count the number $n$ of Bernoulli trials of known probability $p$, until some number of successes $s$ is reached. I'm willing to restrict to $p<0.01$ and $s>100$.

I want the distribution of $n$; or just its variance, for I'm confident the distribution is close enough to a Gaussian of mean $s/p$.

<sub>Up to the last moment before hitting *post* I hoped the answer would emerge from memory, reasoning, web search, or a reference, but..</sub>

---

I get that the distribution of the number of success after some fixed number $m$ of trials (*not* directly what I want) follows a Binomial distribution of parameters $m$ and $p$, which can be approximated by a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=m\cdot p$; and because $\lambda$ is large (about $s$), another valid approximation in the region of practical interest is a Gaussian distribution of mean $m\cdot p$ and standard deviation $m\cdot p(1-p)$. But I fail to progress from there.

Comment: On the matter of web search, a Google search on `"number of trials to" success` (the first search I tried, using key terms only from your post) got useful hits (i.e. ones answering your question) at the [second](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/what-is-the-expected-number-of-trials-until-x-successes) and [third](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/distribution-of-number-of-bernoulli-trials-given-number-of-successes) results (at least for me, you may see slightly different results) - ones that answer your question. I'm left to wonder what you can have searched for.

Comment: @Glen_b: looking back at my cache histrory, I (now) realize that I googled and read on what I identified to be related distributions, first Poisson, then Binomial; and CV articles that where proposed to me on the right; but did not try straight searching for words in my question. My mistake. $\;$ Also I did read the [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/distribution-of-number-of-bernoulli-trials-given-number-of-successes) now linked as related, but wrongly concluded that it was not quite mine.

Comment: Well, you have to get partial credit for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this problem, $n$ follows a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). In R, you can do the usual computations with this distribution (such as finding quantiles) with `dnbinom`, `pnbinom`, and `qnbinom`. Beware that R parameterizes this distribution in terms of the number of failures until a target number of successes, rather than the number of successes until a target number of failures.

Comment: Spot on! That's the (exact) distribution for my problem, after minor adaptations. Thanks.